# Auto-start multiple background user sessions in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, scripting, init-script, autologin, multiuser

I could use some help with what I think is a basic request on the newest edition of Linux Mint (which I think would also be applicable to Ubuntu).

I have a home system with 3GB of RAM and accounts for family members (4 of them). As the initial login process takes 15-20 seconds and kids are impatient, I'd like a way to have an active session auto-started for each user when the system first boots.

... In other words, a multiple auto-login in the background and a normal login screen.

That way, when a user goes to login like normal, their session is already running and is switched to instantly.  I have plenty of RAM and this machine always runs, so is there any way to pull this off via some type of login scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have one user that auto-logs in, you can probably use a script that runs after logging in (use `gnome-session-properties`) that:

- gets a list of users to auto-login from some file
- checks for each of those users if they are logged in yet
- if one is not, use `xdotool` to  switch to the first user (by simulating clicking on Menu and then Logout, etc) *Each of these users must auto-run the script as well, thereby daisy chaining the login process*
- if all users are logged in, switch to some specially marked user (the first) that auto logs in, unless that is the user already currently running the script.

Comment: I'm trying to execute this now, but having to learn a few new concepts along the way.  If I can get this to work, I'll mark it as the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @Slappy_G I have not tried this myself, but that is what I would do. If you get stuck and have any specific questions on `xdotool` etc., you will find some answers here (or you can post a new one).